# Swift required init NSCoder constructor

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, nscoder

I have the following class representing a button in my iOS 8 custom keyboard:

```
internal class KeyButton: UIButton {

    required init(char: Character) {
        super.init()
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Since KeyButton is not initialised via `storyboard` the constructor `(coder: NSCoder)` would never be called.

The problem is that I am required to implement `(coder: NSCoder)` constructor, when I run the app I receive the exception `plugin interrupted` when instantiating `KeyButton`.

Why am I required to implement `(coder: NSCoder)` constructor although I instantiate everything programatically

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the coder. `UIButton`'s `init()` calls `init(frame: CGRect)`, which you haven't implemented. Add the following, and you should be good to go...

```
override init(frame: CGRect ) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    println("Button frame allocated")
}
```